# Trying to make a simple slideshow in Javascript / HTML

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow

I'm trying to make a simple slideshow of images to display on a webpage, but for some reason I'm not getting anything. I'm currently using Mozilla's Thimble WIDE because I'm on a chromebook... So it MIGHT be a limitation of that, but can anyone see any errors in my code?

Currently, I get a box with a relative size of 200x400 (I'm imagining that is the size) that blinks every 2.5 seconds, but never displays an image.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Slideshow Attempt</title>

    <script>
        var slideimages = new Array()
        slideimages[0] = new Image()
        slideimages[0].src = "cleanhouse1.jpg"
        slideimages[1] = new Image()
        slideimages[1].src = "cleanhouse2.jpg"
        slideimages[2] = new Image()
        slideimages[2].src = "cleanhouse3.jpg"
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <img src="cleanhouse1.jpg" id="slide" width="200" height="400"/>
    <script>
        var step = 0

        function slideit() {
            if (!document.images)
                return

            document.getElementById('slide').src = slideimages[step].src

            if (step < 2)
                step++
            else
                step = 0

            setTimeout("slideit()", 2500)
        }

        slideit()
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Call setTimeout in this way: `setTimeout(slideit,2500)` This is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e3ok3s6e/5/)

Comment: this still doesn't display an image?

Comment: That's because there is no image located in that path. You can run this in your local system and put the images in the specified location. The code is working fine..